# ProcessBuilder can't find command, though it can be found in terminal

Tags: java, processbuilder

I have a Java application which starts Mopidy via ProcessBuilder.
This is my code:

```
if(mopidy==null){
     try {
         btnStartMopidy.setDisable(true);
         btnStopMopidy.setDisable(false);
         ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "mopidy");
         pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
         pb.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
         mopidy = pb.start();
     } catch (IOException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
         Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
 }
```

The weird thing is when I run it from Netbeans, the output says the Mopidy command cannot be found, BUT..

**When I run the built .jar file via the terminal, I get the expected Mopidy output.** When I run the .jar file by double clicking on it, I get the same error saying the command cannot be found.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**

This time I tried to invoke the program directly instead of using bash -c.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/local/bin/mopidy");
```

It seems Mopidy can be found now, but I'm getting a different error. It says that a certain Python package (GStreamer, which is required for Mopidy) cannot be found, though it is installed.

Comment: Your `PATH` probably differs; also, any reason why you `-c` instead of directly invoking the program?

Comment: Not really, it was already like this when I started working on the application. See my updated question.

Comment: This is definitely a question of your environment. You may want to dump all of [`System#getEnv`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv--) and compare that with what your shell tells you.

Comment: Ok I did as you said. System.getEnv returns PATH: **/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin** while `printenv` returns a WAY bigger path. So it seems the Java application uses/creates a different path.

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird bug in eclipse that never gets fixed.  Don't restart your eclipse after adding it to PATH variable.  Exit eclipse and start again and it should work.